# Midpoint of two complex numbers in polar form

Tags: complex-numbers

Say we have two complex numbers:

$re^{i\theta}$ and $se^{i\phi}$

Is there a straightforward way to find the polar form of the midpoint of these two complex numbers? I think I'm correct in saying that the argument of the midpoint will be:

$ \frac{\theta+\phi}{2} $

I am asking this question as I had to find the midpoint between two "consecutive" (consecutive as in the sense of adjacent) roots of unity; in this case the moduli of the two complex numbers in question will be the same, but I was wondering if there was any method for the general case. I know we could do it by first converting to Cartesian, but this seems unsatisfactory. Thanks!

Comment: it is not true that argument of the midpoint of two number is the average of their arguments. take for example $1$ and $2i.$

Comment: Where is the problem in trying to find a polar form of $$\frac12 (re^{i\theta} + se^{i\phi})$$

Comment: Not true take the two points $z_1=1$ and $z_2=2i$.  The argument of the mid point is not $\pi/4$ as claimed. There is no straightforward way to express the midpoint in polar form

Comment: @marwalix, why did we come up with the same example?

Comment: @abel I'd have chosen $-1$ and $2$. The argument of $\frac12$ is none of $\pm\frac\pi2$.

Comment: The probability of such an event is zero!

Comment: @marwalix Ah, my apologies. I got confused, because it is true if the two numbers have the same modulus, isn't it?

Comment: And only if they haven't the same modulus

Comment: @marwalix If they have the same modulus, i.e. $ r=s $, what would be the modulus of the midpoint?

Comment: If they have the same modulus the argument if the midpoint is the average of the arguments

Comment: @marwalix Sorry I meant modulus! My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

IF you have $r=s$, then the midpoint $te^{i\psi}$ has

$$
\psi = \frac{\theta+\phi}{2}$$

but not, in general, otherwise.

Comment: No in general $t\neq r=s$. $z_1=1$ and $z_2=i$ you have $r=s=1$ and $t=\sqrt 2/2$

Comment: @marwalix This is what I thought too, this implies that the midpoint lies on a circle along with the other two points.

Comment: @marwalix Ha, true, thanks - corrected, I'm not sure where that mistake came from.